# Where to place python unittests

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
DirA
    __init__.py
    MyClass.py
    unittests   <------------------directory
        MyClassTest.py
```

MyClassTest.py is executable:

```
import unittest
from . import MyClass    

class MyClassTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """ Testcase """

...
.....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I get an error "Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import" at the line:

```
from . import MyClass
```

I would like to place unittests in a 'unittests' directory beside the modules being tested. Is there a way to do this and have access to all the modules in the parent directory which I am testing?

Comment: I prefer to put unit tests outside of the package hierachy, in a separate subdirectory at the root of the project. That way they don't get included in built distributions.

Comment: Sure I can do that too. This is mostly how I would do it in C++ so its a carry over from that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried running the tests like so:

```
cd DirA
python -m unittest discover unittests "*Test.py"
```

This should find your modules correctly. See [Test Discovery](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#test-discovery)

Comment: Just tried it. It wasn't able to find the test. Tried it both from DirA and DirA/unittests. If I directly run it as python MyClassTest.py I get the same "Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import"

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer but I think it was correct before `python -m unittest discover unittests` does that work for you? And then in your test you should be able to simply say `import MyClass`

Comment: Well, it doesnt error out anymore. But it says 0 tests ran.

Comment: If I use your directory structure and filenames then I am able to run the tests with the command in my answer. Make sure you have the `"*Test.py"` in the command to make sure that `MyClassTest.py` is discovered

Comment: Thanks! Adding the "*Test.py" to the end of the command finally worked!!

Comment: Apparently "python -m unittest discover test *" works too if I want all files scanned for test cases.

Answer (score 1):

Use whatever layout you want, depending on your own preferences and the way you want your module to be imported:

- http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap
- https://pytest.org/latest/goodpractises.html

To find your `unittests` folder, since the name is not the conventional one (unit test scripts by default look for a `test` folder), you can use the `discover` option of the `unittest` module to tell how to find your test scripts:

```
python -m unittest discover unittests
```

Note that the first `unittest` is the Python module, and the second `unittests` (with an `s`) is your directory where you have placed your testing scripts.

Another alternative is to use the `nosetest` module (or other new unit testing modules like `pytest` or `tox`) which should automatically find your testing script, wherever you place them:

```
nosetests -vv
```

And to fix your import error, you should use the full relative (or absolute) path:

```
from ..MyClass import MyClass # Relative path from the unittests folder
from MyClass import MyClass # Absolute path from the root folder, which will only work for some unit test modules or if you configure your unit test module to run the tests from the root
```

Comment: Thanks. I have changed into the DirA directory and ran "python -m unittest discover unittests". I have modified the import statement as "from MyClass import MyClass" This throws no errors. But doesn't find the tests either. I get 0 tests run. I have made the file name and class name same now : MyClassTestCase.py & MyClassTestCase

Answer (score 0):

A suggested structure, would be to look at your structure like this:

```
my_app
    my_pkg
        __init__.py
        module_foo.py
    test
        __init__.py
        test_module_foo.py
    main.py
```

Run everything from within `my_app`, this way you will use all the same module references between your test code and core code.